# Sending Apple Push Notification via PushSharp.Core stopped working

Tags: c#, .net-core, apple-push-notifications

A few days ago my code for sending Push notifications stopped working :(

The program began to hang on the last line
**apnsBroker.Stop();**

I use NuGet package PushSharp.Core
https://github.com/mitch-tofi/PushSharp.Core

```
2021-04-27 12:29:58.ПП [DEBUG] Scaled Changed to: 1
2021-04-27 12:29:58.ПП [INFO] Stopping: Waiting on Tasks
2021-04-27 12:29:58.ПП [INFO] Waiting on all tasks 1
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Sending Batch ID=1, Count=1
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Connecting (Batch ID=1)
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Connected (Batch ID=1)
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Sent Batch, waiting for possible response...
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Data Available...
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Finished Read.
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Received 0 bytes response...
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Server Closed Connection...
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Disconnecting (Batch ID=1)
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Disconnected (Batch ID=1)
2021-04-27 12:29:59.ПП [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Done Reading for Batch ID=1, reseting batch timer...
```

My code below:

```
public void sendTestNotification()
{ 
    ..........
    
    // Start the broker
    apnsBroker.Start();
    // Queue a notification to send
    var aps = new Aps();
    aps.aps = new Aps2() { alert = "TestForYou", badge = 0 };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aps);
    apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
    {
        DeviceToken = "MY VALID TOKEN",
        Payload = JObject.Parse(json)
    });
    //}
    // Stop the broker, wait for it to finish   
    // This isn't done after every message, but after you're
    // done with the broker
    apnsBroker.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"APNSBroker stopped");
}
```

Full code is here
https://github.com/emakhankov/ProblemApplePush/tree/main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're looking in to the same issue currently and it seems apple are disabling the old binary interface which push sharp uses.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b

pushsharp has it on the roadmap to support the new interface but not completed yet.

[image: Roadmap]

Found this library which seems easy enough to use as a solution. hope this helps.

https://github.com/alexalok/dotAPNS

Comment: I also tried use 
https://github.com/nvlad/pushsharp.apple.http2 
but no effect too

Comment: Here's what I have found. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/fseydayucel/PushSharpHttpTwo.

If using this for MDM, edit line: https://github.com/fseydayucel/PushSharpHttpTwo/blob/7f15393ea3d7b9528854d950bcc606e4c95097aa/PushSharp.Apple/ApnsHttp2Configuration.cs#L83

to read `if (!commonName.Contains ("ASPS:"))`

And then Recompile.